# When to use DRCP and sessionpool in cx_oracle python?

Tags: python, oracle11g, cx-oracle

For a specific use case - in which I have 100 databases and 1 database is the central database, now my app connects to that one central database which spawns connections to any of the 100 databases as per the request of the user to run some query on any of them. 
In this case does using DRCP makes same as I don`t want the connection to be killed if the user is running the query at the same time I don`t want too many connections to be opened to the db which I control by creating a profile on the database which limits the number of active sessions to some low number say 5 for that specific user(read_only_user) using that specific profile(read_only_profile).

Right now I am using the standard open a connection per request model. But I`m not sure if that`s the best way to go about it.

```
import cx_Oracle
import logging, time


class Database(object):
  '''
  Use this method to for DML SQLS :
  Inputs - Sql to be executed. Data related to that sql
  Returns - The last inserted, updated, deleted ID.
  '''

  def __init__(self, user, password, host, port, service_name, mode, *args):
    #mode should be 0 if not cx_Oracle.SYSDBA
    self.user = user
    self.password = password
    self.host = host
    self.port = port
    self.user = user
    self.service_name = service_name
    self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    try:
      self.mode = mode
    except:
      self.mode = 0
      self.logger.info(" Mode is not mentioned while creating database object")
    self.connection = None
    dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn(self.host, self.port, self.service_name)
    self.connect_string = self.user + '/' + self.password + '@' + dsn
    try:
      self.connection = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connect_string, mode=self.mode,
                                          threaded=True)
      self.connection.stmtcachesize = 1000
      self.connection.client_identifier = 'my_app'
      self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
      self.idVar = self.cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
      error, = exc
      self.logger.exception(
        'Exception occured while trying to create database object : %s',
        error.message)
      raise exc


  def query(self, q):
    try:
      self.cursor.execute(q)
      return self.cursor.fetchall()
    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
      error, = exc
      self.logger.info(
        "Error occured while trying to run query: %s, error : %s", q,
        error.message)
      return error.message


  def dml_query(self, sql):
    try:
      self.cursor.execute(sql)
      self.connection.commit()
      return 1
    except Exception as e:
      self.logger.exception(e)
      return 0

  def dml_query_with_data(self, sql, data):
    """
    Use this method to for DML SQLS :
    Inputs - Sql to be executed. Data related to that sql
    Returns - The last inserted, updated, deleted ID.
    """
    try:
      self.cursor.execute(sql, data)
      self.connection.commit()
      return 1
    except Exception as e:
      self.logger.exception(e)
      return 0

  def update_output(self, clob, job_id, flag):
    try:
      q = "Select output from my_table where job_id=%d" % job_id
      self.cursor.execute(q)
      output = self.cursor.fetchall()
      #Checking if we already have some output in the clob for that job_id
      if output[0][0] is None:
        if flag == 1:
          self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE my_table
                                 SET OUTPUT = :p_clob
                                 ,job_status=:status WHERE  job_id = :p_key""",
                                 p_clob=clob, status="COMPLETED", p_key=job_id)
        else:
          self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE my_table
                                 SET OUTPUT = :p_clob
                                 ,job_status=:status WHERE  job_id = :p_key""",
                                 p_clob=clob, status="FAILED", p_key=job_id)
      else:
        self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE my_table
                               SET OUTPUT = OUTPUT || ',' || :p_clob
                               WHERE  job_id = :p_key""", p_clob=clob, p_key=job_id)
      self.connection.commit()
      rows_updated = self.cursor.rowcount
      return rows_updated
    except Exception as e:
      self.logger.exception(e)
      return 0


  def __del__(self):
    try:
      if self.connection is not None:
        self.connection.close()
    except Exception as e:
      self.logger.exception(
        "Exception while trying to close database connection object : %s", e)


  '''
  if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = Database('test', 'test', 'my_host', '1000', 'my_db', 0)
    columns = db.query('select * from my-table')
    print columns
  '''
```

This is my database class, and I create an object whenever I need a connect to the DB. And the **init** and **del** method take care of constructing and destructing the object.

1. Should I be using DRCP/ sessionPool to improve performance.
2. What if there are too many users waiting coz all the connections in DRCP are taken?
3. Can I have sessionPool per database (for the 100 databases, each database can take atmost 5 connections at a time for that read_only_user)